# Any chance of getting a shorter URL?

Tags: feature-request

This url feels like it's getting longer and longer every time I type it. I love sharing it with people but it is really long... sharepoint.stackexchange.com. Can we do a shorter version? I guess I could make my own tinyurl..

Comment: yeah, i think something like sp.stackexchange.com would be a better solution

Comment: or even spse.com, spexchange.com...

Comment: We could use Sweden's ccTLD and be sp.se? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a shortcut already exists:

> http://s.tk/sharepoint

More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109802/142114).